# Do these 2 sentences have the same meaning?

Tags: relative-clauses

The sentence below shows age restriction for swimming:

> The boys who are 16 years old are allowed to swim.

What if I write this sentence? Does it have the same meaning?

> The boys who are allowed to swim are 16 years old.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add why you think they are different. Otherwise we are just proofreading.

Answer (score 5):

> <s>The</s>  boys who are 16 are allowed to swim.

means any boy who is 16 years old is allowed to swim. (maybe no other group), in this case you'd better drop the "the" to make it general (as it is in the comments)

> The boys who are allowed to swim are 16.

means the boys who are allowed to swim (for any reason) are 16 (maybe by accident!)

The first sentence say who is allowed to swim and is more precise, while the second sentence can imply that you are describing an attribute of the people who get allowed to swim.

Comment: There's truth to this, but it's not clear cut. The first sentence could also be interpreted to mean that the age of the boys is coincidental. Dropping the word "the" would help: "Boys who are 16 years old are allowed to swim." This would make it refers to boys in general and not some specific group of boys. But if you really wanted to be clear, I'd reword the sentence. Like, "Only boys who are 16 years old are allowed to swim."

Comment: @Jay thank you, I edited the answer to reflect your point

Comment: @Ahmad. how about these 2 sentences? is there any difference between them? **the books that have red covers are new.**  **the books that are new have red covers.** thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @amin Here we see how our understanding of the real world changes our interpretation of the sentence. In the case of boys who are allowed to swim, I might well interpret the sentence to mean that there is an age requirement, because it's common for their to be minimum age requirements for various activities. But in the case of new books, I really wouldn't expect there to be a rule that all new books must have red covers, so if I read these sentences, my assumption would be that this is describing a coincidental feature of the books. I can recognize the new books because they have red ...

Comment: ... covers, or they just happen to have red covers. It is, of course, possible that the school puts red paper covers over all new books to identify them, or that the government just passed a law stating that all new books must have red covers. But unless the text spelled something like that out, I wouldn't normally assume it.

Comment: @Jay, your answer is helpful, but i think you didn't answer my question. do the 2 sentences (example books) have the same meaning?

Comment: @amin, Yes they are different, please note when you use "the" you mean some specific books! for example the books on the table. Then you restrict them more (those who have red cover) or (those who are new), the target person should distinguish which are new or which have red covers, then you add extra information about them. "the books that are new have red covers".

Comment: @Ahmad, i exactly got what you said. thank a lot. By the way i am from iran too.

Comment: @amin Nice to hear that, I may say it in this way, when you say "the books that are new have red colors" you may imply any new book has red color, but when you say "the books that have red color are new" you mean any red book is new. but it is possible that there are some blue books which are new too.

Comment: @Ahmad, sorry to ask a lot. according to this [link](http://www.betterwritingskills.com/tip-w022.html) i think what you said about  **"the books that have red color are new"** is wrong. the link says that only the red books are new. what is your idea?

Comment: @amin - that link is somewhere between being poorly worded and being outright incorrect.  They say _So this time, only the red books are new._  But that isn't quite right.  The sentence _"The books that have red covers are new."_ makes no statement one way or the other about any non-red books.  They should have explained it _So this time, the only information provided is that all of the red-covered books are new._  (Native AmE)

Comment: Also -  Be mindful of the difference between "...Books that have red _covers..._"  and  "...Books that have red _colors..._"  The meaning of _"...have red colors..."_ isn't clear to me.  It sounds like it might be describing the range of inks used to print the text inside.

Comment: @Adam, thanks. in a situation that there are blue and red books on the table, doesn't saying **"The books that have red covers are new."** imply that just red books are new?

Comment: Not to me.   If someone said _"There are blue and red books on the table.  The red books are new."_  An almost automatic reaction on my part would be to ask about the blue ones:  _"How about the blue books?  Are they new too?"_  And answers such as _yes," "no"_ and _"we don't know"_ would all be sensible.  At least logically, as isolated statements.  In context, it may be different.( For example if I asked you "which are the new books?"  Then replying "the red books are new" _does_ imply that the blue books are not new.)

Comment: @Adam, what about this sentence? **"boys who are 16 are allowed to swim."** i mean according to you, for example 14 years old boys maybe are allowed to swim. am i right?

Comment: If there was a pile of red and blue books on the table, and someone said, "The books with the red covers are new", I think the general assumption would be that the books with blue covers are not new. Yes, the speaker hasn't actually said that, and if this was some circumstance where a person had a reason to try to trick us -- if it was a salesman or a politician -- I might ask for clarification about the blue books. But to take Amin's example, if the summer camp said, "Boys who are 16 years old are allowed to use the paint ball guns", I'm sure everyone would understand that to mean that ...

Comment: ... younger boys are NOT allowed. Because if 15 year olds were allowed, then they would have said, "Boys who are 15 ...", not "Boys who are 16 ...". Yes, it might depend on context. Like if a parent said, "My son is 16. Is he allowed to use the paintball guns?" someone might reply, "Yes, 16 year olds are allowed ...", especially if he wasn't sure about the minimum. But if someone just declared in general, etc.

Comment: @amin Please note, [the link](http://www.betterwritingskills.com/tip-w022.html) you addressed is about the difference between **that** and **which**, *that* restrict the subject while *which* adds information to the subject. But about your question, it is all about the **subject**, in *new books are red*, the subject is *new books* we don't know anything about *old books*, in *red books are new*, or "books that have red cover are new" the subject is "red books" or "books that have red covers" we don't know about blue books (except we know about other books from the context), but...

Comment: @amin but in "*books, **which** have red covers, are new*" the subject is "books" means "all books" and it says *"all books have red cover and are new."* that is because you used "which" not "that"

Answer (score 0):

They are absolutely **not** the same.

**First sentence**

- Boys who are 16 are allowed to swim.

This means that 16-year-old boys may swim.  It doesn't say whether OLDER boys may swim (nor wheher YOUNGER boys may swim, though the typical reader would assume they may not.) To clarify, you might want to say:

- Only boys who are 16 or older may swim

But there are two things wrong with this rephrasing:

- 1) do any girls get to swim? the original did not specify, but the rephrasing excludes them!
- 2) someone who is, say, 30 is older than 16 but is not a "boy". Will he be allowed to swim?

So, what to say? Maybe this:

- If you are a male, you must be at least 16 to swim [here].

**Second sentence:**

- Boys who are allowed to swim are 16.

This means that all boys allowed into the [swimming place] will be 16 years old—no more; no less. No 8-year-olds, no 19-year olds, nothing but 16-year olds.

This is quite different from the default understanding of the first sentence (16 or older). Try this:

- Males are allowed to swim if they are 16 or older.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, both sentences mean the same thing: the event of being 16 years old and the event of being allowed to swim happen at the same time.

However, think about what these phrases look like when re-worded to speak directly to one of those boys who is too young to swim:

> When you're 16, you'll be allowed to swim.

vs.

> When you're allowed to swim, you'll be 16.

Consider which information is more important, especially when told to a boy who is too young to swim. Such a person wants to know when they are allowed to swim, not when they will turn 16 (the latter being more easily determined by the event of their birthday).

Therefore the first form, which informs the boy of when they will be allowed to swim by using their 16th birthday as a point of reference, is the preferable sentence. The second form may provide the same information, but it's confusing because it's backwards with regards to the boy's interests.

On the other hand, consider an alternate scenario, e.g. in which a parent is visiting a summer camp to inspect it before sending their son to attend. The strict parent sees a group of rowdy boys swimming in a lake and is concerned that their son is too young to swim with them, and so asks the tour guide how old they are. The tour guide could reply:

> "The boys who are allowed to swim are 16."

because the parent knows the boys are allowed to swim, but wants to know their age.

In short: both sentences mean the same thing, but one may be more appropriately worded than the other depending on the context.